# Can you write numpy slicing generically?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do something like

```
x[i, :, :] = (rhs[i, :, :]-diag[i] * x[i+1, :, :])/diag[i]
```

where x and rhs are 3D numpy arrays of size (T,L,S). diag is a 1D array of size T.

This will broadcast properly.

But now I'd like to write a similar function to work on 2D arrays or some other number of dimensions. How can I write this generically so that it will work on any array that has first dimension of size T. I don't want to duplicate code with just a different number of colons since there are a lot of these kinds of lines in the function.

Comment: Are you wanting to vectorize over `T` as well? That is, is this happening in a `for i in range(T)` loop?

Comment: Did you mean the number of axes are not guaranteed to be 3? Can it be 1, 2, 3, ..., N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x[i] = (rhs[i] - diag[i] * x[i+1])/diag[i]
```

Those colons are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Didn't realize it was so simple.

Comment: If you're interested in doing something similar, but along the last dimension, you can use an ellipsis like `x[...,i+1]`.